# Pass variable (not attributes) to laravel factory create method

Tags: laravel

**This is Laravel 7**

Is it possible to pass a variable to a factory and have that variable get passed down another level?

Here is a factory I'll be generating:

```
$factory->define(CustomerReview::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'customer_id' => function() {
            return factory('App\Customer')->create($PASS_VARIABLE_HERE)->id;
        },
        'review_request_id' => function() {
            return factory('App\ReviewRequest')->create()->id;
        },
        'nps' => $faker->numberBetween($min = 0, $max = 10),
        'feedback' => $faker->text()
    ];
});
```

Note this part:

```
'customer_id' => function() {
            return factory('App\Customer')->create($PASS_VARIABLE_HERE)->id;
 },
```

The `CustomerFactory` is

```
$factory->define(Customer::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'location_id' => function() {
            return factory('App\Location')->create()->id;
        },
        'first_name' => $faker->firstName,
        'last_name' => $faker->lastName,
        'email' => $faker->unique()->safeEmail,
        
    ];
});
```

I already have a Location created that I need to pass from the `CustomerReviewFactory` down into the `CustomerFactory`

In other words, I want to pass a `$location->id` into the `CustomerReviewFactory` which then gets passed in the generated `CustomerFactory`

`$review = factory('App\CustomerReview')->create([], $EXISTING_LOCATION_ID);`

Comment: It's kinda unclear how you already have the Location in the `CustomerReviewFactory`, but you could use [Overriding Attributes](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/database-testing#creating-models).

Answer (score 0):

```
$factory->define(CustomerReview::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    $location = 'SOMETHING';
    return [
        'location' => $location,
        'customer_id' => function() {
            return factory('App\Customer')->create(['location' => $location])->id;
        },
        'review_request_id' => function() {
            return factory('App\ReviewRequest')->create()->id;
        },
        'nps' => $faker->numberBetween($min = 0, $max = 10),
        'feedback' => $faker->text()
    ];
});
```